# We don't recognized your account error by yahoo

Tags: email, yahoo

Can anyone assist in identifying the error as our Yahoo emails are becoming disabled after 1 or 2 days?

Also the accounts which are working from many days are getting disabled, we are doing warmup for server and sending large amount of emails on that email account.

What are the specific reason for the disabling and how we can overcome this issue attaching the image of issue

I am expecting that some provide reason why its happening and how i can solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.